# How to connect a prototype cell in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a tableview in the storyboard, and a custom prototype cell. I've set the cell identifier in the storyboard, and am trying to dequeue it and am getting:

unable to dequeue a cell with identifier  TTEntry - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

I can't see anything else in the storyboard TableCell properties to link it with. I just don't know what the message is getting at.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Screwtape.

Comment: Can we see the code that's dequeuing the cell?

Answer (score 14):

From Storyboard:

1. In Attribute Inspector set Reuse Identifier [image]
2. Add your CustomCell class in your storyboard like mentioned by Jignesh Agola

From code (like lemon lime pomelo posted) :

```
[self.tableView registerClass:<Your UITableViewCell subclass> forCellReuseIdentifier:<Your identifier>]
```

Comment: you missed one step when dequeuing the cell cast it to your custom class 

guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kCellReuseId, for: indexPath) as? YouCustomCellClass

Answer (score 2):

Add your CustomCell class in your storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to either 1) add your CustomCell class as mentioned by Jignesh, or 2) register the nib programmatically in the UITableViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "yourCellIdentifier", bundle: nil)
self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"yourCellIdentifier")
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that code - having converted the code to objective C, but still I get the same error message. `    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TTEntry" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TTEntry"];
`

Comment: did you put that code in viewDidLoad (or some other place before the call to dequeue the cell with that identifier)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Search Display Controller

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[YourClass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"yourCellIdentifier"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
tableview.register(YourClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourIdentifier")
```

if you code without storyboards, xibs, etc.