# Must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view when when you tap into one of it's rows, it will instantiate another `UITableViewController`. However, I have getting this code: `must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard`

Here is the storyboard:

[image]

Here is my code

The first UITableViewController

```
class MainActivityViewController: UITableViewController {

    let node = MenuStructure.structure.childenNode

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return node.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = node[indexPath.row].value
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedNode = node[indexPath.row]
        let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)

        navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //self.navigationItem.title = MenuStructure.structure.value

    }
}
```

Then when you tap into one of it's row it will segue to this UITableViewController

```
class SubMenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    let node: Node

    init(node: Node) {
        self.node = node
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("required initializer not implemented")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return node.childenNode.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = node.childenNode[indexPath.row].value
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
   }
}
```

I have tried registering my cells but I don't understand how and don't know where to put it.

Any suggestions are welcome!thanks!

***UPDATED CODE***

```
class SubMenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    let node: Node

    init(node: Node) {
        self.node = node
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("required initializer not implemented")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return node.childenNode.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = node.childenNode[indexPath.row].value
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewController.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up the cell identifier in the storyboard ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066205/how-to-connect-a-prototype-cell-in-a-storyboard

Comment: The controller I'm trying to instantiate isn't in the storyboard so I can't set up my cell identifier

Comment: Where is it then ? Are you creating it using code only ?

Comment: The instantiation is from the 'MainActivityViewController' under 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register cell in viewDidLoad method , since this method is called once so it will be registered once, then tableview will reuse this type of cells by dequeing

Please modify your code like this:

```
class SubMenuViewController: UITableViewController {

        let node: Node

        init(node: Node) {
            self.node = node
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("required initializer not implemented")
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return node.childenNode.count
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = node.childenNode[indexPath.row].value
            return cell
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

       }
    }
```

Comment: @BrendonCheung I wrote UITableViewCell.self and you wrote UITableViewController.self, please change this in viewDidLoad method

Comment: @BrendonCheung By registering the cell we are telling the tableview to use this type of cell, whenever you want to reuse cell, we can also register our custom cell class by tableView.register(MyCustomCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell"), so tableview will use MyCustomCellClass type of cells in tableview

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate your help!

Comment: @BrendonCheung Glad, I could help